# JavaのCompiler Toolsでコンパイルするjavaファイルに独自のjavaファイルを継承させたいがシンボルを見つけられませんと言われる

Tags: java

javax.toolsを用いてコンパイルしたいjavaファイルがあるのですが、別の自作のjavaファイルをimportしているため シンボルを見つけられません と出てしまいます。
(aaa.javaはbbb.javaをextendsしたいがaaa.javaをコンパイルする際エラーを吐く)
importしたいファイルが膨大なためコンパイルしたいファイルにそれらを直接書き込むこともできません。何か方法はありますでしょうか？

プログラミング経験が少なくお恥ずかしい限りですがご容赦ください。

失礼しました。
こちらがコンパイルするためのコードになります。

```
public class DoCompile {
    public DoCompile() {
        File f = new File("D:/Desktop/compiletest/aaa.java");
        File d = new File("D:/Desktop/compiletest/classes");

        String[] args = {
            "-d", d.getAbsolutePath(),
            f.getAbsolutePath()
        };

        JavaCompiler c = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        int r = c.run(null, null, null, args);
        System.out.println("return" + r);
        if(r == 0)
            System.out.println("BUILD SUCCESSFUL");
    }
}
```

aaa.javaはまったく別のjavaファイル、bbb.javaを継承しているファイルです

開発環境(IDE):Eclipse 　使用言語 Java7

Comment: 例示できるサンプルコードなどありませんか? あったら質問内に貼り付けると、良い回答が得られやすくなりそうです。

Comment: 失礼しました。コンパイル用のコードを貼りました。
importしたいというよりは継承しようとした結果importすることになります。

Comment: bbb.java はどういう形でどこに置いてありますか? もしかしてコンパイル済みで classes ディレクトリの下に置いてあったりしますか?

Comment: どうすればいいか検討がつかなかったため、bbb.javaはeclipseでリンクを張り、ビルド対象にしてあります

Comment: `importしたいファイルが膨大なため` っていうのは、 bbb.java のような aaa.java をコンパイルするのに必要となるクラスファイルが他にも沢山ある、という理解で良いでしょうか?

Comment: はい、それもありますがbbb.javaがとても長いコードのためaaa.javaの中に入れたくないというのもあります

Comment: お二方とも、ありがとうございました。
KoRoN様のgithubにあるコードを使ってみたら、できました。

Answer (score 1):

以下の2点が必要です。

1. あるディレクトリ (例えば `./src`) の下に aaa.java や bbb.java 他、必要なファイルを置く
2. `-sourcepath` オプションで前述のディレクトリを指定する

`-sourcepath` は、コンパイルするのに足りないクラスファイルのソース(今回の場合はbbb.java)を探す場所を指定するオプションです。このオプションの存在は [javac のドキュメント](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) やヘルプに記載されています。

これを利用することで、コンパイルを実行する側のコードは以下のような感じになるでしょう。なお、質問中に書かれたコードから一部簡略化している箇所がありますが、適宜読み替えてください。

```
public class DoCompile {
    public static void main(String[] unused) {
        String[] args = {
            "-d", "./classes",
            "-sourcepath", "./src",
            "./src/aaa.java"
        };
        JavaCompiler c = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        int r = c.run(null, null, null, args);
        if (r != 0) {
            System.out.printf("build failed: %d\n", r);
        }
    }
}
```

実際に試せるサンプルコードを https://github.com/koron/ja-stackoverflow-22453 においておきました。コンパイルするファイル名が多少変わっていますが、基本的な構造は同じだと考えています。ご参考までに。

Answer (score -1):

必要なクラスがインポートできてないからシンボルが見つからないんじゃないでしょうか

```
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.File;
```

これ追加すれば、コンパイルは通ると思います

Comment: importとpackageは省略しているだけで、importはしてあります
問題はaaa.javaにコンパイルをかけようと思っている時にaaa.javaが継承しているbbb.javaがないと言われていることです

Comment: すいません。勘違いしていました。
クラスパス内に依存関係のあるソースファイル（bbb.java)があれば、aaa.javaのコンパイルは通ると思います。
恐らくbbb.javaがクラスパス内に存在しないことが原因だと思うので、aaa.javaとbbb.javaが同じディレクトリ内にあればコンパイルは通ると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。すぐに試してみます。